# $\sqrt{x+1}, \sqrt{x+2}, \sqrt{x+3}$ cannot be all three rational numbers.

Tags: radicals, rational-numbers

$x$ is a rational number. Then,
$\sqrt{x+1}, \sqrt{x+2}, \sqrt{x+3}$ cannot be all three rational numbers. Any idea? Thanks!

I tried to solve this problem and I arrived to prove that in natural set (positive integers) we cannot have:
$m^2 + n^2 = k^2$ and
$m^2 + 2n^2 = l^2$.
Also is rather easy to see that $m$ is odd, $n$ is even, also $n$ is multiple of $3$.

But I'm not sure that is the way.

Comment: I have change the context. Can you open the question?

Comment: YOu should have a thereom that a square root of a rational number is rational if and only if the rational number is the ratio of two perfect squares.  SO if this were true you would have to have $x + 1 = \frac {a^2}{b^2}; x + 2=\frac {c^2}{d^2}; x+ 3= \frac {m^2}{n^2}$ for integers $a,b,c,d,m,n$.  Prove that is impossible.

Comment: @fleablod
I've tried. That is why m, n, k and l appeared. (See the text in the question). 
Also, as you can see, we have numbers in arithmetic progresion, and I know we can have as: 1, 25, 47 - but I don't know if the ratio could be a perfect square.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say we have perfect squares in arithmetic progression like 1, 25, 49 ... but I don't know if the ratio ($n^2$) could be also perfect square.

Comment: Let $x$ be a rational number.
Then the following numbers $\sqrt{x+1}, \sqrt{x+2}, \sqrt{x+3}$ cannot be simultaneously rational.

Consider:
$x+1 = \dfrac{m^2}{n^2}$

$x+2 = \dfrac{m^2 + n^2}{n^2}$

$x+3 = \dfrac{m^2 + 2n^2}{n^2}$

The numerators must be perfect squares, so:

$m^2 = m^2$
$m^2 + n^2 = k^2$
$m^2 + 2n^2 = l^2$

It's rather simple to see that $m$ is odd (so $k$ and $l$) and $n$ is even.
As well, $n$ is multiple of $3$. ...Further? (Or: otherwise?...) (Not so good the formatting in commentary way...)

Answer (score 1):

**Partial Answer**

Let $x=\frac pq$ where GCD$(p,q)=1$. So, $x$ is in lowest possible terms.

Note if $p,q$ are two integers, then $p+q$, $p+2q$ and $p+3q$ will all leave different remainders upon division by $3$. Now note that, if $q\neq 3k$, GCD$(p+q,q)=$GCD$(p+2q,q)=$GCD$(p+3q,q)=1$, hence none of the fractions are further reducible.

Hence , there will always be one of the numerators of $3k+2$ form, since, as stated before, all leave different remainders. There is no perfect square of $3k+2$ form. Hence, no matter if $q$ is a perfect square or not, that particular number can never be rational.

If $q=3k$, $p=3m+2$ or $p=3m+1$. In the former case, the same argument applies, and a perfect square is impossible. However I'm still struggling with the latter case. Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: For the case $q=3k$  they dont leave different remainder when divided by 3.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to solve this problem and I arrived to prove that in natural set (positive integers) we cannot have: $m^2 + n^2 = k^2$ and $m^2 + 2n^2 = l^2$.

By definition, having $k^2-n^2 = m^2$ and $k^2+n^2=l^2$ would mean that $n^2$ is a [congruum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruum). But there exists no congruum that is a perfect square itself, by [Fermat's right triangle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_right_triangle_theorem):

> - *A right triangle in the Euclidean plane for which all three side lengths are rational numbers cannot have an area that is the square of a rational number. The area of a rational-sided right triangle is called a [congruent number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruent_number), so no congruent number can be square.*
>
>   [...] *equivalent to:*
> - *If three square numbers form an arithmetic progression, then the gap between consecutive numbers in the progression (called a [congruum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruum)) cannot itself be square.*

Comment: Proved by Fermat prior to 1670? Wow....

Comment: @AdamRubinson That was the age of enlightment in more ways than one ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Note that your question is equivalent to showing that for a rational $x$, all of $\sqrt{x-1}$, $\sqrt{x}$ and $\sqrt{x+1}$ cannot be rational. If possible, on the contrary, let that be true.

Let $x=\frac{a^2}{b^2}$ with $(a,b)=1$ so that
\begin{align}
\sqrt{x-1}&=\frac{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{b}\\
\sqrt{x}&=\frac{a}{b}\\
\sqrt{x+1}&=\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{b}
\end{align}

Since, $\sqrt{x+1}$ is rational, then $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ must be an integer. So,
$$a^2+b^2=c^2$$
which implies
\begin{align*}
&a=p^2-q^2\\
&b=2pq\\
&c=p^2+q^2
\end{align*}
for some integers $p,q,r$.

Similarly, $\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$ should also be an integer. So,
$$(p^2-q^2)-4p^2q^2=x^2$$
for some integer $x$, which is not possible because of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4184995/943723).

This completes the proof.

Is that okay?

Comment: Why are you assuming that $x$ is a square rational?

Comment: @md2perpe I assumed that $\sqrt{x}$, $\sqrt{x+1}$, and $\sqrt{x-1}$ are rationals and arrived at a contradiction.

Comment: Ah, you had redefined $x$.

Comment: @md2perpe Yeah, I should have written "let $\sqrt{x}=\frac{a}{b}$" instead. That way, it would have been less confusing, I guess

Comment: @SayanDutta - If what is written here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4184958/prove-that-the-expression-p2-q22-4p2q2-cannot-be-a-perfect-square/4184995#4184995 is true, then the problem is solved. (I cannot follow that with elliptic curves, etc...)

Comment: @SayanDutta "$(p^2-q^2)-4p^2q^2=x^2$" — It would be more clear if you wrote it as $(p^2-q^2)^2-4p^2q^2=d^2$ instead. This fixes the missing square, and uses another variable $d$ on the RHS, not to be confused with the previously defined $x$.

Comment: @JulianK The elliptic curve formulation is just another way to state the same [Fermat's right triangle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_right_triangle_theorem). From the linked wikipedia page: "*the only rational points on the elliptic curve $y^{2}=x(x-1)(x+1)$ are the three trivial points with* $x\in \{-1,0,1\}$ *and* $y=0$".