# Prove that the expression $(p^2-q^2)^2-4p^2q^2$ cannot be a perfect square

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I was solving a different question which came down to-

> Prove that the expression $(p^2-q^2)^2-4p^2q^2$ cannot be a perfect
> square. In other words, prove that the equation
> $$(p^2-q^2)^2-4p^2q^2=x^2$$ does not have any solutions in
> $\mathbb{N}$.

I checked on Wolfram Alpha and found no solutions (except those with $p=0$ or $q=0$ which I'm not interested in).

I also feel like it's not very hard to prove it, especially if you look at an alternate form
$$p^4+q^4=6p^2q^2+x^2$$
which looks similar to $a^4+b^4=c^2$ (with another extra term), about which we know that no solutions exist (in $\mathbb{N}$).

But, these are all just talking in air. Can anyone give me a complete proof of this fact? Thanks in advance.

Comment: For what it's worth (arguably not much), after reading [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple), I asked myself whether positive integers $p,q,d,m,n$ could exist such that $(2mnd) = (2pq)$ and $[d(m^2 + n^2)] = [(p^2 - q^2)].$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$p^4+q^4=6p^2q^2+x^2\tag{1}$$

Let $U=\frac{p}{q}$, then we get

$$V^2 = U^4-6U^2+1\tag{2}$$

An equation $(2)$ is birationally equivalent to the elliptic curve
$$Y^2 = X^3 - X \tag{3}$$
with $$U = \frac{X-1}{Y}, V = \frac{X^3-3X^2+1+X}{Y^2}$$

According to [LMFDB](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/32/a/3) , elliptic curve has three integer points as follows.

$(X,Y)=(\pm 1,0), (0,0)$

Since this elliptic curve $(3)$ has rank 0, then there are no rational points on the curve.

Thus, there are no positive integer solutions $(p,q).$

Comment: That seems perfect! Thanks!

Comment: @SayanDutta this is Theorem 3 on page 18 of Mordell, Diophantine Equations. Chapter 4 begins on page 16, Theorem 1 is $x^4 + y^4 = z^2$ has only trivial solutions, which is FLT for degree 4. He does this with Fermat's `infinite descent' which is elementary

Answer (score 0):

Since $x,y$ are real numbers, $x^4$ can be represented as $a^2+b^2+2ab$ at least for two $a,b$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Thus if it be true then $x^4+y^4=(a+ b)^2+(l+m)^2$ which cannot be a perfect square for any $l,m$ in $\mathbb{R}$. As the twice product term cannot be zero for nonnegative $a,b,l,m$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: In any triangle ABC it has been proven by S.L.Loney that AB^2+AC^2=2( AD^2+DC^2),where D is the middle point of BC. Thus using this geometric proof we can see if a perfect square can be written as sum of two squares e.g. 5^2=4^2+3^2,and it be product of twice terms of two real numbers,then the expression is possible for some real numbers expressing again as multiple of 2,and 2^2=2*2,and there exist rational square roots of said real numbers,but the expression may not be unique.